# Is there an extension which overlays the file name in the text editor?

Tags: visual-studio

I have happened to find out that Web Essentials puts Generated in the text editor in Visual Studio.

Does anyone know of an extension where it would overlay the file name instead, for instance in this case it would say header.component.css?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

**WhereAmI** is a simple extension that adds a layer on the background of your edit code window with a recap of your position in the current project.:

[Visual Studio 2012, 2013.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErosFratini.WhereAmI)

[Visual Studio 2015.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErosFratini.WhereAmI2015)

[Visual Studio 2017.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErosFratini.WhereAmI2017)